# как сделать подобный PreferenceScreen как на скриншоте

Tags: java, android, ui

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как лучше такое сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Возможно и есть более изящное решение, но мне лично на ум приходит только один вариант - делать все через recyclerView. Я понимаю что это супер тяжелое и кривое решение но лично я другого пока не вижу. То есть вы делаете один адаптер, и три списка расположенных в каком-нибудь linearLayout в столбик. И в эти списки вы посылаете данные для каждого элемента списка. Таким образом вы заполняете три списка. А чтобы сохранить все значения, я бы предложил использовать sharedPreferences или бд. Для сохранения вы можете либо нажимать кнопку "сохранить", либо обновлять данные при нажатии на +/-. Надеюсь что-то из моего ответа поможет в решении вашей проблемы. Удачи :)

Answer (score 2):

Перегружается Preference и метод onBindView для перехвата View, в разметке или программно указывается на макет справа [android:widgetLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#attr_android:widgetLayout), назначаются слушатели происходит инициализация и т.п.